# Bus Error : Core dumped when using numpy memmap

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

I'm trying to perform calculations on very large arrays, dimensions 65536 x 65536. Since I read that np.memmap can allow me to perform calculations out of core so that I'm not limited by memory I tried to do this. This method works for small arrays like 8192 x 8192. However, when I try for the larger dimension, I get a bus error(core dumped). What could be causing this issue? And how can I overcome it? Would appreciate any advice. Code is below. I have 2 arrays X and Y, stored in binary format which I load and perform calculations on. Additionally, I have a RAM of 128 GB so there is no issue in these new arrays being allocated.

```
import numpy as np 

X = np.memmap('X.bin',dtype='float64',mode='r',shape=(65536,65536))
Y = np.memmap('Y.bin',dtype='float64',mode='r',shape=(65536,65536))

A = np.fft.rfft2(np.fft.fftshift(X))
B = np.fft.rfft2(Y)
C = np.fft.irfft2(A*B)
alpha_x,alpha_y = np.gradient(C,edge_order=2)
```

Together, this would be

```
alpha_x,alpha_y = np.gradient(np.fft.irfft2(np.fft.rfft2(Y)*np.fft.rfft2(np.fft.fftshift(X))),edge_order=2)
```

Comment: Which instruction leads to the bus error? That line is pretty long and a lot could happen there. Can you split the operations over several lines?

Comment: the last one, I can, I just made it into one line so that multiple arrays are not created which would increase memory usage...Let me edit the post to show the breakdown

Comment: Are you sure that you have 128GB RAM? That sounds quite a lot for non-server/clusters.

Comment: Yes its a server pc, definitely have 128 GB ram because I run other calculations taking up around nearly the same amount. I also have sufficient hard disk space, which is irrelevant anyway since I haven't got to the part of saving the alpha arrays.

Comment: So each of your arrays is 32GiB? Then 128GB is not enough to store all of your data

Comment: So the only two arrays are alpha x and y... The two input arrays are from disk yes? A B and C are just the breakdown of the single long line I've given below ....so they don't actually take up memory? I thought that's what I'm trying to avoid by memmap

Comment: `A`, `B` and `C` all take up memory at the same time, as do `C`, `alpha_x`, and `alpha_y`. Combining into one line shouldn't affect the memory usage. It looks like all the arrays are the same size - so that already uses up 75% of your available space. It wouldn't surprise me at all if either `rfft2` or `gradient` allocate some temporary arrays which make things worse. Saving C to a file and memmapping it might help

Comment: Actually, adding `del A`, `del B` after the line creating `C` might be enough

Comment: Seems like this is the only option, those temporary arrays are the issue...Thanks for the advice